# How can I count specific elements that contain a specific element?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Considering xml like:

```
<Main>
   <ActivityOne>
       <!-- this should be counted -->
       <TaskA>yes</TaskA>
       <TaskB>do do do</TaskB>
   </ActivityOne>
   <ActivityTwo>
       <ActivityFive>
           <TaskA>da da da</TaskA>
       </ActivityFive>
   </ActivityTwo>
       <ActivityOne>
           <!-- this should not be counted -->
           <TaskC>yadda yadda</TaskC>
       </ActivityOne>
   <ActivityThree>
       <ActivityOne>
           <!-- this should be counted -->
           <ActivityFour>
               <TaskA>yes</TaskA>
           </ActivityFour>
           <TaskC>nope</TaskC>
       </ActivityOne>
       <ActivityTwo>
           <TaskF>no</TaskF>
       </ActivityTwo>
   </ActivityThree>
   <ActivityFour>
       <TaskA>nope</TaskA>
   </ActivityFour>
</Main>
```

I am trying to count the number of "ActivityOne" elements that contain one or more "TaskA" elements anywhere within.

I tried this:

```
int count = xDoc.Descendants("ActivityOne").Where(x => x.Descendants("TaskA").Count() > 0).Count();
```

But it only seems to count the ActivityOne elements that have a TaskA deeper than a direct child.

Comment: "But it only seems to count the ActivityOne elements that have a TaskA deeper than a direct child.", then what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Doesn't `count` equal `2`?  Isn't this what you want? I see two "this should be counted" comments in your question.

Comment: No, it only counts the third "ActivityOne" and not the first giving a count of one. I am looking for two.

Comment: I tested this and it is giving me 2. Are you sure you are posting the correct XML?

Comment: That might be the case. There is more logic it is doing that I thought wouldn't effect the linq-to-xml query but maybe it is.

Comment: Yes, your expression is totally fine for this xml

Comment: You guys are right. Another part of the code was broken. Thanks for the help! I'll give you points if you want to post an answer that it works fine.

Comment: @sean I've posted the answer with your approach and I've also added one more possible solution for this problem using XPath. If you think that this answer is helpful you could accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have provided is totally fine:

```
int count = xDoc.Descendants("ActivityOne")
                .Where(x => x.Descendants("TaskA").Count() > 0)
                .Count();
```

I would like to add one more solution which can help you to solve this problem using XPath:

```
int count = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ActivityOne[descendant::TaskA]").Count();
```

It's a little bit shorter expression and, in my opinion, it's a better approach if you need to select some elements from XML using special conditions.

Comment: I need a count of "ActivityOne" only if "TaskA" is anywhere within.